# Как избавится от символов ^M и лишних пробелов на github?

Tags: github, phpstorm

Как избавится от символов ^M и лишних пробелов на github? Я сделал задание и запушил на github. В итоге на гите у меня получилось в некоторых задания нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в некоторых заданиях вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже в phpstorm поставил: line separator unix and osX

Уже и в гите прописывал: git config --global core.autocrlf true

Создавал новый файл после всех этих настроек и писал код заново - все бестолку. Как это исправить?